# Update Subtract qty - SQL

Tags: php, sql, database

I have the following DB structure

`Table product` (which holds my products information including the stock)

- prod_id
- prod_name
- prod_desc
- prod_price
- stock

table `store_orders_item` (which is updated every time a customer buys from the my site)

- id
- order_id
- sel_prod_id
- sel_prod_price
- sel_prod_qty

I need that every time I make a sale online and `store_orders_items` is updates, that reduce the stock field of the product sold on the table `product`

I think i need to use the code below, plus some sort of join or subquery to update my product table according to the `prod_id`, but i could not figure out how.

```
UPDATE product SET stock = stock - (SELECT   SUM(sel_prod_qty) FROM  store_orders_items);
```

I also tried:

```
UPDATE product
SET    stock = stock - (SELECT   s.sel_prod_qty, s.sel_prod_id, p.prod_id
FROM  store_orders_items as s left join product as p ON
s.sel_prod_id=p.prod_id WHERE order_id=(SELECT MAX(order_id) from orders_number));
```

And got this error:
"You can't specify target table 'product' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I have try to add this line but does not work. 
WHERE prod_id=(SELECT  sel_prod_id
                            FROM  store_orders_items);

Comment: This is the wrong approach.  Once you've subtracted a particular orders quantity from the stock level - that's it.   So when you create a new order, create the new store_orders_items, and in another statement, just subtract the same amount from the stock - ONLY using the amount entered and not using the store_orders_items table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use join updates, for example in MySQL:

```
UPDATE
    product p
INNER JOIN
    store_orders_item s 
ON
    p.prod_id = s.sel_prod_id
SET
    p.stock = p.stock - s.sel_prod_qty
WHERE
    s.order_id = NNNNN
```

where **NNNNN** is the id of order just inserted.